# Where to load and store settings from a file?

Tags: design, language-agnostic, file-handling

I think this question should apply to most programs that load settings from a file. My question is from a programming point of view, and it is really how to deal with the loading of settings from a file in terms of different classes and accessibility. For instance:

- If a program had a simple `settings.ini` file, should its contents be
  loaded in a `load()` method of a class, or perhaps the constructor?
- Should the values be stored in `public static` variables, or should
  there be `static` methods to get and set properties?
- What should happen in the event of the file not existing or not being readable? How would you let the rest of the program know it can't get those properties?
- etc.

I'm hoping I'm asking this in the right place here. I wanted to make the question as language agnostic as possible, but I'm mainly focusing on languages that have things like inheritance - especially Java and C#.NET.

Comment: For .NET, it is best to use App.config and the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class to get the settings

Comment: @Gibson I'm just starting out in .NET so could you link me to any good tutorials for that class?

Comment: Stackoverflow has lots of answers on it. Quick search reveals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114527/simplest-way-to-have-a-configuration-file-in-a-windows-forms-c-sharp-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043530/what-is-app-config-in-c-nethow-to-use-it There will also be lots of info on MSDN, starting here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228063(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Gibson Thank you for those links. They will be very useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a really important question and it is often done wrongly as it is not given enough importance even though it is a core part of pretty much every application. Here are my guidelines:

Your config class, which contains all the settings should be just a plain old data type, struct/class:

```
class Config {
    int prop1;
    float prop2;
    SubConfig subConfig;
}
```

It should not need to have methods and should not involve inheritance (unless it is the only choice you have in your language for implementing a variant field - see next paragraph). It can and should use composition to group the settings into smaller specific configuration classes (e.g. subConfig above). If you do it this way it will be ideal to pass around in unit tests and the application in general as it will have minimal dependencies.

You'll likely need to use variant types, in case configs for different setups are heterogeneous in structure. It is accepted that you'll need to put a dynamic cast in at some point when you read the value to cast it to the right (sub-)configuration class, and no doubt this will be dependent on another config setting.

You should not be lazy about typing in all the settings as fields by just doing this:

```
class Config {
    Dictionary<string, string> values;
};
```

This is tempting as it means you can write a generalised serialisation class that doesn't need to know with what fields it's dealing, but it is wrong and I'll explain why in a moment.

Serialisation of the config is done in a completely separate class. Whatever API or library you use to do this, the body of your serialisation function should contain entries that basically amount to being a map from the path/key in the file to the field on the object. Some languages provide good introspection and can do this for you out of the box, others you'll have to explicitly write the mapping, but the key thing is you should only have to write the mapping once. E.g. consider this extract I adapted from the the c++ boost program options parser documentation:

```
struct Config {
   int opt;
} conf;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("optimization", po::value<int>(&conf.opt)->default_value(10);
```

Note that the last line basically says *"optimization" maps to Config::opt* and also that there is a declaration of the type that you expect. You want the reading of the config to fail if the type is not what you expect, if the parameter in the file is not really a float or an int, or doesn't exist. I.e. Failure should occur when you read the file because the problem is with the format/validation of the file and you should throw an except/return code and report the exact problem. You should not delay this to later in the program. That's why you should not be tempted to have a catch all Dictionary style Conf as mentioned above which won't fail when the file is read - as casting is delayed until the value is needed.

You should make the Config class read-only in some fashion - setting the contents of the class once when you create it and initialise it from file. If you need to have dynamic settings in your application that change, as well as const ones that don't, you should have a separate class to handle the dynamic ones rather than trying to allow bits of your config class to be not read-only.

Ideally you read in the file in one place in your program i.e. you only have one instance of a "`ConfigReader`". However, if you're struggling with getting the Config instance passed around to where you need it, it is better to have a second ConfigReader than it is to introduce a global config (which I'm guessing is what the OP means by "static"), which brings me to my next point:

Avoid the seductive siren song of the singleton: "I'll save you having to pass that class class around, all your constructors will be lovely and clean. Go on, it'll be so easy."
Truth is with a well designed testable architecture you'll hardly need to pass the Config class, or parts of it down through that many classes of your application. What you'll find, in your top level class, your main() function or whatever, you'll unravel the conf into individual values, which you'll provide to your component classes as arguments which you then put back together (manual dependency injection). A singleton/global/static conf will make unit testing your application much harder to implement and understand - e.g. it will confuse new developers to your team who will not know they have to set global state to test stuff. It will also prevent you from running unit tests in parallel.

If your language supports properties you should use them for this purpose. The reason is it means it will be very easy to add 'derived' configuration settings that depend on one or more other settings.
e.g.

```
int Prop1 { get; }
int Prop2 { get; }
int Prop3 { get { return Prop1*Prop2; }
```

If your language doesn't natively support the property idiom, it may have a workaround to achieve the same effect, or you simply create a wrapper class that provides the bonus settings. If you can't otherwise confer the benefit of properties it is otherwise a waste of time to write manually and use getters/setters simply for the purpose of pleasing some OO-god. You'll be better off with a plain old field.

You might need a system to merge and take multiple configs from different places in order of precedence. That order of precedence should be well-defined and understand by all developers/user e.g. consider windows registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
You should do this functional style so that you can keep your configs read only i.e.:

```
final_conf = merge(user_conf, machine_conf)
```

rather than:

```
conf.update(user_conf)
```

I should finally add that of course if your chosen framework/language provides its own built-in, well-known configuration mechanisms you should consider the benefits of using that instead of rolling your own.

So. Lots of aspects to consider - get it right and it will profoundly affect your application architecture, reducing bugs, making things easily testable and sort of forcing you to use good design elsewhere.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the answer. Previously when I have stored user settings I have just read from a file such as an `.ini` so that it is human readable, but are you suggesting that I should serialize a class with the variables in?

Comment: .ini is easy to parse, and there are also lots of APIs that include .ini as a possible format. I'm suggesting that you use such APIs to help you do the grunt work of the textual parsing but that the end result should be that you have initialised a POD class. I use the term serialise in the general sense of copying to or reading in the fields of a class from some format, not the more specific definition of serialising a class directly to/from binary (as is typically understood for say java.io.Serializable).

Comment: Now I understand a bit better. So essentially you are saying having one class with all the fields/settings in, and have another to set the values in that class from the file? Then, how should I get the values from the first class in other classes?

Comment: Case by case basis. Some of your top level classes might just need a reference to the whole Config instance passed into them if they rely on so many parameters. Other classes just need one or two parameter maybe, but there is no need to couple those to the Config object (making them even easier to test), just pass the few parameter(s) down through your application. As mentioned in my answer, if you build with a testable/DI oriented architecture getting the values where you need them will generally not be difficult. Use global access at your peril.

Comment: So, how would you suggest that the config object is passed to classes if inheritance does not need to be involved? Through a constructor? So, in the main method of the program, the reader class is initiated which stores values in the Config class, then the main method passes the Config object, or individual variables to other classes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first two questions. To answer your third - yes, basically.

Comment: In answering my third question, you did essentially answer the others. All I was asking is how I should get the Config objects to other classes, but I'm gathering the Config object should just be passed when creating an instance of the class?

Answer (score 5):

In general (in my opinion), it's best to let the application deal with how the configuration is stored, and pass the configuration into your modules. This allows flexibility in *how* the settings are saved so that you can target files or webservices or databases or...

Plus, it puts the burden of "what happens when things fail" on the application, who knows best what that failure means.

*And* it makes it tons easier to unit test when you can just pass in a configuration object rather than having to touch the filesystem or deal with concurrency issues introduced by static access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't quite understand it. I'm talking about when writing the application, so there isn't anything to deal with the configuration, and therefore, as a programmer, I do know what a failure means.

Comment: @andy - sure, but if the modules access configuration directly, they don't know what context they're working in, so they cannot determine how to handle configuration issues. If the application is doing the loading, it can deal with any issues, since it knows the context. Some apps might want to fail over to a default value, others want to abort, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify here, by modules are you referring to classes, or actual extensions to a program? Because I'm asking about where best to store settings actually inside the code to the main program and how to allow other classes access to the settings.  So I want to load a configuration file and then store the setting somewhere/somehow so I don't have to keep referring to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET for programming the classes, you have different options like 
Resources, web.config, or even a custom file.

If you use Resources or web.config, the data is actually stored in XML file, but, the loading is faster.

Retrieving the data from these files and storing them in another location will be like a double use of memory as these are loaded into memory by default.

For any other file or programming language, the above answer by Benedict will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the slow reply. Using the Resources would be a good option, but I've just realized that it's probably not the best option for me seeing as though I plan to develop the same program in other languages, so I'd rather have an XML or JSON file but read it in my own class so that the same file can be read in other programming languages.